# hapi : Cannot start server before plugins finished registration

Tags: mongodb, hapi.js

I am getting error on initial setup with Hapi and MongoDB and I am getting error after starting my server.

Code:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
var Boom = require("boom");

const dbOptions = {
  url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/comparekaro",
  settings: {
    db: {
      native_parser: false
    }
  }
}

const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
  port   : 3001,
  router : {
    stripTrailingSlash : true,
  },
  routes : {
    cors : true,
  }
});


server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: (request, reply) => {
    var db = request.server.plugins['hapi-mongodb'].db;
    var ObjectID = request.server.plugins['hapi-mongodb'].ObjectID;

    db.collection('catalogs').find((err, result) => {
      if (err) return reply(Boom.internal('Internal MongoDB error', err));
      reply(result);
    });
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{name}',
  handler: (request, reply) => {
    reply(`i am ${request.params.name}`);
  }
});

server.register({
    register: require('hapi-mongodb'),
    options: dbOptions
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
});

server.start((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

Comment: How do you think repeating the same sentence three times will help?

Comment: You should probably mention what the error is.

Comment: Hello Imtiaz, don't give up because of the negative votes. Try to stay active on SO. Do you still need a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Move server.start callback inside the server.register callback, these are async operations that need to be run in a logical order.